# USB Headset and Sonic Suite III/Realtek Audio

Tags: usb, audio, drivers

I have a USB headset (Sades SA-903) and a laptop (ASUS ROG G703VI) with a Realtek sound card (or perhaps just drivers, i'm unsure - listed on speccy as 'Realtek High Definition Audio').

Realtek's bundled sound management program Sonic Suite 3 has an equalizer function but it doesn't work with USB headsets (or USB anything) and appears to be some kind of abandonware from how many problems the internet is full of people having with it.

Other third party equalizers i've tried do not function whatsoever with Realtek causing me to lose sound functionality entirely or have all kinds of issues.  I want to use an equalizer with my existing USB headset.  I'm unsure if I can remove Realtek without issues, but if I can i'm certainly fine to do that.

What are my options here, if any?

EDIT:  Attempting to install Voicemeeter Banana + VBcable led to sound cutting out entirely if realtek selected, or no effect on sound otherwise.

As far as I can tell the problem appears to be some interaction between the realtek driver/programs and sound modification programs that results in sound cutting out entirely or no modification of the sound occurring.  Equalizer APO does function but other programs don't seem to, when following their installation guides/messing about with settings to try to work around this somehow.

What i'm specifically looking to do is compress the sound (which voicemeeter banana can do but not equalizer APO).  When following the steps in installation guides of sound applications that can do this, they aren't working, and some google searches show a lot of users having issues of this kind specifically involving realtek drivers - that's where my guess at the cause comes from.

Comment: Never tested it [not on Windows] but people have mentioned using [Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/) - sometimes alongside stuff from Voicemeeter, like [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm)

Comment: After your edit - Realtek is nothing to do with your USB headset, that's for the onboard sound. Your headset will show as its own device & perhaps control panel.

Answer (score 0):

As Tetsujin commented above, Realtek embedded (onboard) audio and external USB audio headset are completely different hardware devices. 
Below is the [MS audio architecture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/windows-audio-architecture). Notice the grey-colored functions called "sound effects", they appear to be "vendor-specific". Therefore the Realtek equalizer won't work on arbitrary USB audio headset. Mixing and matching conflicting pieces of audio software causes the mess.

[image]

If you want to use the USB headset with special effects, you should try to disable the Realtek on-board audio in BIOS and remove EVERY proprietary piece of associated software. Then you will have a better luck with third-party sound effect software to work with the standard USB audio class.